# Continuous spectrum of multiplication operator in $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the multiplication operator
by the idependent variable on the space $L_2(R)$. It is defined by

$(Mu)(t) = tu(t), t \in R$ a.e.

$dom(M)$ consists of all measurable functions $u$ which satisfy

$$ \int_{R}(1+t^2)|u(t)|^2dt < \infty $$
Show that $\sigma _c =\mathbb{R}$.

Let $t \neq t_0$ and  $$g_{\varepsilon} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{gdy $|t-t_0|< \varepsilon $}\\
0 & \textrm{gdy $|t-t_0| \ge \varepsilon$}
\end{array} \right.$$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t-\lambda)fg_{\varepsilon}dx=\int_{|t-t_0|<\varepsilon}(t-\lambda)fdx \xrightarrow{\varepsilon \to 0}0$$
It follows that $g_\varepsilon=0$, because $ran(t-\lambda)$ is dense but I don't know how it's imply that $\sigma_c=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: A bounded operator has bounded spectrum..

Comment: My operator isn't bounded, because $t$ isn't in $L_{\infty}$, my bad. So what can i use to prove this equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that the continuous spectrum is $\Bbb R$, you want to show that $M-\lambda I$ has dense range. Meaning that if $g$ is such that $\langle (M-\lambda I) f, g\rangle=0$ for all $f$, then $g\equiv 0$.

However, $\langle (M-\lambda I) f, g\rangle = \langle (t-\lambda) f, g\rangle$. Pick a delta sequence that is centered around $x_0$ for $x_0\neq \lambda$.

I think this should help.

Comment: I should add that you should show the spectrum must be real by showing $M-\lambda I$ has a bounded inverse for complex $\lambda$. This is not too hard to do.

Comment: So if $Ran(T)$ is orthogonal only to $g=0$ then $Ran(T)$ is dense? Why is that?

Comment: That's a general theorem of Hilbert spaces. If $X$ is dense, every $g$ can be approximated by elements in $X$. However if $g$ is orthogonal to everything in $X$, then it is orthogonal to every element of a sequence in $X$ converging to it. You can easily conclude $g$ must be $0$ from that.

Comment: That make sens. I will try to use your hint then. I used the sequence from the task I did before. So let $t_0 \in R: \ t-\lambda \neq 0$ a.e. and $g_{\varepsilon}(x)=f(x) for |t_0-\lambda | \ge \varepsilon$ and $0$ otherwise. It follows that $g_{\varepsilon}$ is convergent to $f$ so $Ran(t-\lambda)$ is dense. I could also prove this using orthogonal property as you wrote without sequence? The second part about boundedness I proved in other task.

Comment: @Cameron-could you check it?

Comment: I don't follow your solution very well. Maybe add it to your post and solicit feedback. Make sure to include all details.

Comment: @Cameron-I already edited my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108146/discussion-between-krzysztofb-and-cameron-williams).